# Mobile redirection via htaccess for different countries

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, geo

I use this mobile htaccess redirection code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url1 [R=302,L]
```

Now, I want to keep that code, but also to redirect mobile users from some specific countries to different url2. How can I do this?
Is the code below is the solution /is this possible both codes to exists in htaccess/?

```
RewriteEngine On - /for all users/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url1 [R=302,L]

RewriteEngine On - /only for Ca, US and MX for example/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|US|MX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url2 [R=302,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you've installed and loaded the mod_geoip module (more info [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/)). Then you want your rules to be the other way around, since the first rule would simply match all countries, redirect, and the second rule will never be reached:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|US|MX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url1 [R=302,L]
```

Alternatively to using `GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE`, you could also use:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE} ^NA$
```

for all of North America.

Comment: Than you, Jon Lin, but it seems, that I must upgrade my Apache from 2 to 2.2, which is risk for me. Do you know some other way to redirect different countries to different urls in . htaccess except the mod_geoip option? Thank you.

Comment: Can I use only %{COUNTRY_CODE} or %{ENV:COUNTRY_CODE} instead of %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}?